# In VBA how to move down on webpage till complete webpage loading

Tags: vba, mouseevent, data-extraction

I am working on webpage data extraction and my code is extracting data properly but code is extracting data of only first page.Actully webpage having feature of data loading when mouse is moving down i.e second page is loaded when mouse moved down and then third and fourth vice versa on mouse move down.I am using following code for data extraction and code is working fine but only for first page,Is this possible that all pages will be loaded and then i will start extraction.

URL: https://www.trendyol.com/kadin-spor-outdoor-x-g1-c104593?sst=MOST_RATED

Code

```
http.Open "GET", url, False                                       
http.Send                                                         
html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText                           
html1 = html.body.innerHTML                                       
Set tdata = html.getElementsByClassName("p-card-chldrn-cntnr")    
For Each Item In tdata                                            
href2 = Item.getElementsByTagName("a")                            
href2 = Replace(href2, "about:", "")
```

Comment: Monitor the web traffic as you scroll in network tab of browser. Quick glance (not double checked) looks like requests for additional info are like this `https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-searchgw-service/v2/api/infinite-scroll/sr/kadin-spor-outdoor-x-g1-c104593?sst=MOST_RATED&pi=2&storefrontId=1&culture=tr-TR&userGenderId=1&pId=0&scoringAlgorithmId=2&categoryRelevancyEnabled=false&isLegalRequirementConfirmed=false&searchStrategyType=DEFAULT&productStampType=TypeA`  where perhaps pi is the query string param to alter.

Comment: But if we are using pi as page number then after 150 to 200 pages records are duplicate

Comment: Did you get my point?

Comment: Products are changing on pi basis but how to extract all product from above url http.ResponseText having only one product data